# How can the input shape of a CNN be modified?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm following [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00367.pdf) paper to create a super resolution CNN. The paper splits training images into smaller sub-images to train on. To do the same, I used a sub-image size of 96x96. My model looks like this:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # features
    model.add(Conv2D(d, 5, input_shape=(96, 96, 1), padding="same"))
    model.add(PReLU())

    # shrinking
    model.add(Conv2D(s, 1, padding="same"))
    model.add(PReLU())

    ... more convolution layers

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, 9, strides=scale_factor, padding="same"))
```

This gives an output image upscaled by the scale factor. This works fine and when trained, outputs a good quality image. However, I can only input 96x96 images. I would like to be able to input any image and get the correctly upscaled output. The issue with this is that the number of parameters for the PReLU activation layer change with input size. I assume using ReLU would avoid this problem since there would be no additional parameters. However, the paper authors seem to have avoided this problem, and I would like to do the same.

So is there any way for me to be able to pass in arbitrary sized images? I can't seem to figure out how it was done by the paper authors

Comment: Currently, there's no way to pass arbitrary sized images to a Keras model. A fixed input size is required in order to compute the shapes of the filters ( in a Conv layer ).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you train your network on specific input size and after that it cannot work with arbitrary image, as it will only accept the resolution (input size). If you want it to work with arbitrary images you will have to add a function, that will resize images before they go to your CNN.

Comment: That's definitely not the case, the paper split images into much smaller sub images, the final results were shown on full size images